# Swap values and indexes in numpy

Tags: numpy

I wonder if this is possible, so I have two 2D arrays:

```
X[7][9] = 10
Y[7][9] = 5
```

From above info I want to create following two 2D arrays:

```
X'[5][10] = 9
Y'[5][10] = 7
```

Is it possible to accomplish this? Values of X and Y are bounded and won't exceed shape of X and Y. Also X and Y has the same shape.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your question? Do you want to transpose the arrays?

Comment: kind of yes. this is for image processing, X to X' is mapping where a pixel in original image is landing (coordinates) in transposed image.

Comment: It's better to use `x[7,9]` indexing syntax

Comment: Give us a small sample pair of arrays.  That way it will easier to generate and test a solution.  In other words, a good answer will include a working example (this catches typos and bigger errors); you can save us some set up work.

Comment: Any chance of duplicates?  If so, how do you resolve the conflict?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`np.nditer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html#numpy.nditer) to keep track of the [multi-index](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#tracking-an-index-or-multi-index) and the corresponding values of the arrays.

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
X = rng.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(10, 10))
Y = rng.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(10, 10))

X_prime = X.copy()
Y_prime = Y.copy()

it = np.nditer([X, Y], flags=['multi_index'])
for x, y in it:
    i, j = it.multi_index
    X_prime[y, x] = j
    Y_prime[y, x] = i
```

I believe this is the result you were expecting:

```
>>> X[7, 9], Y[7, 9]
(3, 9)
>>> X_prime[9, 3], Y_prime[9, 3]
(9, 7)

>>> X[1, 2], Y[1, 2]
(8, 2)
>>> X_prime[2, 8], Y_prime[2, 8]
(2, 1)
```

Comment: `np.ndindex` also generates these indices (internally using `nditer`).

Answer (score 0):

```
In [147]: X = np.random.randint(0,5,(5,5))                                      
In [148]: Y = np.random.randint(0,5,(5,5))
```

Similar to Matt's answer, but using `ndindex` to generate the indices. There are various ways of generating all such values.  Internally I believe `ndindex` uses `nditer`:

```
In [149]: X_,Y_ = np.zeros_like(X)-1,np.zeros_like(Y)-1                         
In [150]: for i,j in np.ndindex(*X.shape): 
     ...:     k,l = X[i,j], Y[i,j] 
     ...:     X_[k,l] = i 
     ...:     Y_[k,l] = j 
     ...:                                                                       
In [151]: X                                                                     
Out[151]: 
array([[2, 4, 3, 4, 2],
       [0, 3, 0, 2, 3],
       [1, 1, 4, 4, 4],
       [2, 1, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 4]])
In [152]: Y                                                                     
Out[152]: 
array([[1, 2, 1, 3, 0],
       [4, 2, 4, 0, 4],
       [4, 3, 3, 2, 1],
       [0, 3, 0, 2, 2],
       [1, 4, 2, 0, 0]])
In [153]: X_                                                                    
Out[153]: 
array([[-1,  4,  4, -1,  1],
       [ 4, -1, -1,  3,  4],
       [ 3,  0,  3, -1, -1],
       [-1,  0,  1, -1,  1],
       [ 4,  2,  2,  2, -1]])
In [154]: Y_                                                                    
Out[154]: 
array([[-1,  0,  2, -1,  2],
       [ 3, -1, -1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  0,  3, -1, -1],
       [-1,  2,  1, -1,  4],
       [ 4,  4,  3,  2, -1]])
```

Notice that with randomly generated arrays, the mapping is not full (the -1 values).  And if there are duplicates, the last replaces previous values.

Handling duplicates - note the change in `X_`:

```
In [156]: for i,j in np.ndindex(*X.shape): 
     ...:     k,l = X[i,j], Y[i,j] 
     ...:     if X_[k,l]==-1: 
     ...:         X_[k,l] = i 
     ...:         Y_[k,l] = j 
     ...:     else: 
     ...:         X_[k,l] += i 
     ...:         Y_[k,l] += j 
     ...:          
     ...:                                                                       
In [157]: X_                                                                    
Out[157]: 
array([[-1,  4,  7, -1,  2],
       [ 4, -1, -1,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  0,  3, -1, -1],
       [-1,  0,  1, -1,  1],
       [ 4,  2,  2,  2, -1]])
```

If the mapping is complete and one to one, it might be possible to do this mapping in a whole-array non-iterative fashion, which would be faster than this.